# How to make a single-file executable python 2.7 x64 on windows?

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

after seeing this :  [Single-File Stand-alone Python 2.7.9 for Windows](http://www.orbitals.com/programs/pyexe.html)

I want to make a similar thing for latest python 2.7.11 x64, but since py2exe doesn't support single file packaging in x64 mode. I used cx_freeze, and successfully generated a package, but cx_freeze has no single file option.

so I tried [IExpress](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables), and 7-zip sfx module, but both of them can't run py.exe in the same console, and they can't pass parameters to the extracted exe file. what other options do I have?

here is my python script:
https://gist.github.com/oglops/a641b0185ed903ab1d1c

if you try the py.exe from the original author, it has some command line arguements and it runs in the same console, so it can be used like this

```
py.exe  <some py script>
```

Comment: `pyinstaller --one-file <some py script>`

Comment: pyinstaller doesn't work out of the box, tons of error messages. since the original author had his setup.py. so I tried cx_freeze first.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install [pyinstaller](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#how-to-install-pyinstaller) which can be got like this:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Then from the python folder you [generate the spec](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#what-pyinstaller-does-and-how-it-does-it) like this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed myscript.py
```

Open the spec file and make sure everything is correct.

Then you use the spec to build the app like this:

```
pyinstaller.py --onefile myscriptsname.spec
```

---

If you get this error buiding the spec:

> ImportError: No module named six

Then you also need to install [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) using this:

```
pip install six
```

More info on [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/):

> Six is a Python 2 and 3 compatibility library. It provides utility functions for smoothing over the differences between the Python versions with the goal of writing Python code that is compatible on both Python versions. See the documentation for more information on what is provided.
>
> Six supports every Python version since 2.6. It is contained in only one Python file, so it can be easily copied into your project. (The copyright and license notice must be retained.)

Comment: At what step did you get the errors? Install or building the spec or building the app?

Comment: when building the spec

Comment: I installed this and the error is gone .... although I don't know what this is. `pip install six`

Comment: "Six is a Python 2 and 3 compatibility library. It provides utility functions for smoothing over the differences between the Python versions with the goal of writing Python code that is compatible on both Python versions. See the documentation for more information on what is provided." https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyInstaller to do this, but you have to work around some of the ways it hooks various modules, since PyInstaller expects your goal is a self-contained application and not a Python interpreter.  I recently moved the code that Shuman referenced into a GitHub project that uses PyInstaller to build stand-alone versions of Python 2.7, 3.5, and 3.6 in 32-bit and 64-bit variants.  See https://github.com/manthey/pyexe.